# Multiple keys in dictionary after group by from data table c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, datatable

I am currently fetching multiple columns from excel.

Excel format is like below

```
 StudentId   StudentTempId    Department    Address       TotalMarks
 1           100              IT            Brooklyn      90
 1           100              IT            Manhattan     80
 2           200              HR            Boston        50
```

A single student can have multiple addresses that's why after fetching the data from excel into data table I am first applying group by and then converting it into a dictionary. I have applied the group by on 2 columns StudentId and StudentTempId. Because of which two keys are getting created when converting to a dictionary. For now, I have created a tuple having the same two items and rest 3 fields I am adding in the value of dictionary in the form of StudentDetail class which is as follows:

```
public class StudentDetail
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int TotalMarks { get; set; }
}
```

Below code I have written to fill all the excel data in an object:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, List<StudentDetail>> StudentDetailList 
      = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
      .GroupBy(row => Tuple.Create
       (
          row.Field<int>("StudentId"),
          row.Field<int>("StudentTempId")
       )).
       ToDictionary
       (
          dict => dict.Key,
          dict => dict.Select(row => new StudentDetail
          {
             Department = row.Field<string>("Department"),
             Address = row.Field<string>("Address"),
             TotalMarks = row.Field<int>("TotalMarks")
          }).ToList()
        );
```

Is there any other good way besides using Tuple as a combination of keys?

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

`Tuple` is good for combined keys because its implementation of `GetHashCode` actually uses all of the values to generate the hash code. This is also true for `ValueTuple`.

What you want to avoid is using a struct without overriding `GetHashCode` because it will use the implementation defined in `ValueType`, which simply calls `GetHashCode` from the first value in the struct. This may cause a lot of collisions if multiple keys have the same value as their first member. This will not break your code but it will reduce the performance of the dictionary.

You can look up these implementations here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com

I suggest `ValueTuple` if you are using C# 7.0 or higher since there is a literal you can use for it. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/

Answer (score 0):

Use a UInt64 as the key to combine the ints of the tuple using bit shifts.

```
Dictionary<UInt64, List<StudentDetail>> StudentDetailList
 = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(row => new UInt64(       
      (UInt64)(row.Field<int>("StudentId"))<< 32 |
      (UInt64)(row.Field<int>("StudentTempId"));
   )).
   ToDictionary
   (
      dict => dict.Key,
      dict => dict.Select(row => new StudentDetail
      {
         Department = row.Field<string>("Department"),
         Address = row.Field<string>("Address"),
         TotalMarks = row.Field<int>("TotalMarks")
      }).ToList()
    );
```

Bitwise operations are intrinsic to modern processors and should yield a magnitude increase in performance(assuming a 64-bit process and no negative values).
To separate the key back out, if needed, use the following code:

```
int StudentId = key >> 32;
int StudentTempId = key && 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Comment: I would be curious to see performance comparisons between this and a ValueTuple solution because I'd expect the compiler to optimize away ValueTuple.

Comment: I'm not a huge expert on it, but I've been told that boxing is only required when the type of the object isn't known at compile time, like when you use an interface.

Comment: Overriding GetHashCode is only required if you use a struct (well not required, but important). The default GetHashCode implementation for ValueTuple generates the hash code from all of the values.

Comment: If the OP is using C# 7, you have the more compact solution with ValueTuples, However, my solution works with all versions of C# without heap allocations as required by Tuples.

Comment: That's true. I would expect the original Tuple class to reduce performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the `StudentId` and `StudentTempId` as part of the `StudentDetail` model then I'd say it's a good approach as you can simply get the corresponding list given a key by:

```
var studentDetails = StudentDetailList[Tuple.Create(1, 100)];
```

You could make the syntax a bit nicer by grouping on `ValueTuple` i.e.

```
.GroupBy(row => (row.Field<int>("StudentId"),
                    row.Field<int>("StudentTempId")))
```

In which case you'd access it as:

```
var studentDetails = StudentDetailList[(1, 100)];
```

If however, you're fine with having the aforementioned properties in the `StudentDetail`  i.e. `StudentId` and `StudentTempId` then you could get back a `List<IEnumerable<StudentDetail>>` by performing:

```
var studentDetails = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row =>
            (
                row.Field<int>("StudentId"),
                row.Field<int>("StudentTempId")
            )).Select(g => g.Select(row => new StudentDetail
            {
                StudentId = g.Key.Item1,
                StudentTempId = g.Key.Item2,
                Department = row.Field<string>("Department"),
                Address = row.Field<string>("Address"),
                TotalMarks = row.Field<int>("TotalMarks")
            })).ToList();
```

Whenever you need to find a specific group of student details you can query it as:

```
var result = studentDetails.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Any(e => e.StudentId == 1 && e.StudentTempId == 100));
```

or using `FirstOrDefault` depending on which you find most appropriate:

```
var result = studentDetails.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Any(e => e.StudentId == 1 && e.StudentTempId == 100));
```

Comment: This solution loses the ability to search for a student/class in log n time.  By directly implementing this as a DataTable, Your best search will be in n time.